# inserting an element in unordered_map gives error

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

I have defined an `unordered_map` like this

```
struct pht {
  pht(int t, vector<bool> pat) 
: tag(t), pattern(32) {}
private:
  int tag;
  vector<bool> pattern;
};

unordered_map< pair<int, int>, pht > predictor;

int main()
{
  int pc, addr, offset, tag;
  vector<bool> pat;
  srand(time(0));

  tag = 1000; pc = 100; offset = 10; 
  for ( int i = 0; i < 32; i++ ) 
  pat.push_back( rand() % 2 );
  predictor.insert(make_pair( make_pair(pc, offset), pht(tag, pat) ) );
  return 0;
}
```

However I get this error:

(UPDATED)

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'size_t'
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: `predictor.insert(` expects a `std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, pht>` as the parameter, not a key followed by a value.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't read the documentation...

Comment: I followed like the example in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/

Comment: @mahmood: No you didn't...

Comment: Please next time post a **complete, minimal** code. Yours is at the very least lacking several headers and some `using` statements, making it unnecessarily hard to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is misleading; the real reason is that there’s no `std::hash` specialisation for `std::pair<int, int>` which is required by `unordered_map`. You need to either provide this specialisation or (recommended) create an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which specifies a custom hasher:

```
struct hash_pair {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    std::size_t operator ()(std::pair<T, U> const& p) const {
        using std::hash;
        return hash<T>()(p.first) ^ hash<T>()(p.second);
    }
};
```

And then declare the map as:

```
unordered_map<pair<int, int>, pht, hash_pair> predictor;
```

Comment: I recommend [a non-template predicate with a template `operator()`](http://ideone.com/qgNUtE)